# Getting raw string (or bytes) for a double value in rapidjson parsing?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

Is there a way to get underlying bytes for a double value while parsing json using rapidjson.

Look at below code:

```
string temp_json2 = "{\"byte_size\":1000.3}";
rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.Parse<0>(temp_json2.c_str());

rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator iter = doc.MemberBegin();

const rapidjson::Value& key = iter->name;
std::cout << key.GetString() << " = "; 

const rapidjson::Value& val = iter->value;
std::cout << val.GetDouble();
```

I want to get something like

val.GetRawString(); instead of val.GetDouble();

Reason I need this is that I don't want any precision to be lost during conversion. Note that I don't have a choice to modifying json to put quotes around double value.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We're having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is possible:

```
{
    "hash": "00000000206d413bdd4d020a7df959176440e7b52f120f3416db11cb26aaaa8f", 
    "bigint": 13671375398414879143589706241811147679151753447299444772946167816777, 
    "time": "1551597576", 
    "special": false
}
```

```cpp
rapidjson::Document document;
document.Parse<rapidjson::kParseNumbersAsStringsFlag>( JSONmessage );

std::cout << document["hash"].GetString() << std::endl;
std::cout << document["bigint"].GetString() << std::endl;
```

Source: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues/1458

Answer (score 1):

Currently no.

I am working on a "full-precision" parsing option (for quite long time) which can be precisely parse string into `double`. The `double`-to-string conversion is already exact using grisu2 algorithm. But if a string cannot be represented by `double` precisely, it will still lose some precision.

To support your requirement, it may need to add an parsing option, and changing the SAX and DOM interface. If you would like this feature to be implement, please report [here](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/issues) for further discussion.

Comment: In my case I have a json with doubles. I parse it, make minor changes (add new array elements) and serialize. Json constantly gets huge amount of changes because of doubles in it and this process is endless: next time I make changes, many double change again and again. I either have to store that array as serialized json string (and I need to parse twice) or I need to parse json manually